# View follows object when object moves? How do I turn this off?

Tags: 3d-view

I did something unbeknownst to me and have made my view constantly follow an object. If i move that object it remains constant in the center of my view while the rest of the scene moves around instead.

What is this setting? I've tried pressing <kbd>.</kbd> on the number pad and it did nothing.

[image]

Comment: That question addresses a different issue, @gandalf3.

Comment: @RossM. Er.. How so?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but that question you linked to dealt with orbiting about a certain point, while this question had to do with tracking an object (no orbiting involved.  just panning)

Comment: @gandalf3 because that question addresses bizarre rotation issues with the viewport not the view locking to an object.

Comment: Yes. On further review, it's related (the lock to object setting did fix the issue for that question too).  But this one is a different issue. It just happens to have a similar fix.

Comment: @RossM. I disagree. They are the exact same problem, just asked differently.

Comment: The exact same _solution_.  Not the exact same problem.

Comment: @RossM. I don't see where you are coming up with different problem.. Both users accidentally enabled *lock to object*, and were subsequently confused as to why their viewports where acting differently. Anyway, if you don't think it's a duplicate, that's fine :) That's why there is a voting system.

Comment: Well this is a matter of my opinion, but to me, the only thing that the two questions share is the source of the issue (and therefore the fix).  They don't, however, exhibit the same side effects.  Analogy: two people can have the flu (same source of the issue) but experience two different side effects (one experiences coughing, the other sneezing.)  They can both be fixed by the same means, and come from the same source, but are different issues.

Comment: Yes! :)  All good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

Press the N key to bring up the right tool bar, and delete your cog object from the Lock to Object field.

Comment: Thank you, it's always a simple fix, just finding it is troublesome.

Comment: No problem.  A lot of stuff to do with the viewport setup (visibility of grid, axes, clipping, AO, matcaps, etc) are found in the N panel, so if you run into something you need to change in your viewport setup, odds are, it'll be in there.